Missing default behaviors in R for VSC. Or are they somewhere in settings?
In trying out Rscript in MS VSC for convenience (without Radian - don't like the esthetics), I am missing two features of RStudio when running code one line at a time.
If you take a look at the screen capture below, library(MASS) is called twice, because the cursor does not advance automatically to the next line after running a line of code as it does in RStudio.
Second, you can see that I messed up when running sigma because it is split in several lines, but found no way of escaping the + trap, besides killing the R terminal.
Any tricks, macros, JSON add-ons to make this feel a bit more like RStudio?

